# Making scrolls in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jscrollpane

Good time of the day, I'm trying to add scrolls to the `GridBagLayout` but definitely missing the correct way to do it.

The code:

```
public GUI(Map map)
{
    //declare image icons and try to read them
    ImageIcon missing = new ImageIcon();
    ImageIcon wall = new ImageIcon();
    ImageIcon floor = new ImageIcon();
    //set texture for missing cases
    try
    {
        Image tempImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/images/missing.png"));
        missing = new ImageIcon(tempImage.getScaledInstance(16, 16, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        Image tempImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/images/wall.png"));
        wall = new ImageIcon(tempImage.getScaledInstance(16, 16, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        tempImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/images/floor.png"));
        floor = new ImageIcon(tempImage.getScaledInstance(16, 16, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    for (int i=0;i<map.getMapSize();i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<map.getMapSize();j++)
        {
            c.gridy=i;
            c.gridx=j;
            if (i==0 && j==0)
            {
                c.weightx=1;
                c.weighty=1;
            }
            else
            {
                c.weightx=0;
                c.weighty=0;
            }
            c.gridwidth=1;
            c.gridheight=1;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            JLabel tile = new JLabel(missing);
            if (map.getElementAt(i, j)==0)
            {
                tile.setIcon(wall);
            }
            else
            {
                tile.setIcon(floor);
            }
            pane.add(tile, c);
        }
    }
    //c.gridx=map.getMapSize();
    JScrollPane thePane = new JScrollPane();
    pane.add(thePane, c);

    setTitle("Game GUI");
    setSize(640, 480);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

As far as I understand adding `JScrollPane` just after filling the pane is incorrect and of course it fails. The question is: how to add them correctly in this case? The aim overall I'm trying to achieve is to be able to scroll (move) the map in the game if it exceeds the game window size.
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: you have to add JPanel (instead of Container pane = getContentPane();), put all JComponents to JPanel (change default FlowLayout to proper LayoutManager), then this JPanel put to JScrollPane, JScrollPane to JFrame.CENTER (add(thePane);), JScrollBar(s) will be visible in the case that PrefferedSize from JPanel is greater than JViewport from JScrollPane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the issue is that you try to add the GridBagConstraints to the JScollPane instead of adding your JPanel....

```
JScrollPane thePane = new JScrollPane();
pane.add(thePane, c);
```

try this:

```
JPanel myMapPanel = new Jpanel();
myMapPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
// add all the stuff to myMapPanel here (do the looping stuff here)
JScrollPane thePane = new JScrollPane(myMapPanel);
pane.add(thePane, c);
```

take care of this:

```
new JScrollPane(myMapPanel);
```

Comment: Overall, I have to exchange `Container pane = getContentPane(); pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` with `JPanel myMapPanel = new Jpanel(); myMapPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());`
Add elements inside the loop to JPanel. And afterwards : `JScrollPane thePane = new JScrollPane(myMapPanel);
pane.add(thePane, c);`
Did I understand right?

Comment: not really... its just the case that you add en empty JSrcoll-Pane to your main panel. You need to give the Scrollpane a component (JPanel) inside to be scrolled. (Means the JScrollpane is like a border 7 parent component and scrolls the component which is inside).

Comment: So, I should have `JPanel` (say main), which should contain another `JPanel` (say map) with layout and other components, and I should add `JScrollPane(map)` to the main, correct? Otherwise I'm confused.

Comment: Correct.

    main panel contains jscrollpane
    jscrollpane contains mapPanel

Comment: Finally got it, thanks for wasting your time and help!:)